# Are an A O proposition an exclusive OR relationship?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

It **seems** this way because

1. only one and one alone **must** be true
2. 1  $\implies$ both cannot be true
3. 1 $\implies$ together cannot be false
4. 1 $\implies$ individually propositions can be false

Truth Table below

```
A O       A ex-OR O
0 0       0
0 1       1
1 0       1
1 1       0
```

Please check if my analysis is true. If yes, does any book have this ? Copi and Tidman do not *seem* to have it. I have truth table for other square of opposition relationships too but wanted to start by asking this question.

Comment: What is an "A O proposition" ?

Comment: In the Aristotelian analysis of [Categorical propositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_proposition#Translating_statements_into_standard_form) we have "A prop" and "O prop"...

Comment: I mean in the square of oppositions, is contradiction (A - O link) an exclusive or relationship ?

Answer (score 1):

See [Square of opposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_of_opposition): the relation of *contradiction* between "All S are P" and "Some S are **not** P" is an "exclusive" relation.

The two are [contradictory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/#AffDenCon) and

> exactly one member of any contradiction is true and one false: they cannot both be true, and they cannot both be false.